# Impala table small file issue

Tags: hadoop, impala

I have a table of 10 TB in size which has 2k+ partitions, each partition has around 300 small files,
could you please help me to fix the small file issue without affecting the directory structure.
I have tried the shuffle option which is reducing the files for small tables but not working for huge tables.

Comment: Please go through [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), specifically the sections on [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It is always preferable to know [how to debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Not sure, why number of impala partition file matters to you? Let impala/hadoop handle them.